# Archivo ibd particionado y recontruirlo

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, ubuntu, servidor

Tengo un problema sobre transferencias de archivos entre servidores ubuntu 18.04, y el problema empieza con todos los archivos en general, tengo una aplicación de transferencia entre servidores, el problema es el peso de los archivos (no mayor a 2 mb por archivo), el sistema funciona correctamente hasta que llega al tope de mb para la transferencias, y estos archivos .ibd llegan a sobrepasar por mucho el máximo de transferencia.

Una vez contextualizados, he ensayado dividir el archivo en varios "sub archivos", primero utilizando el split (funciono bien), pero luego tratar de reconstruir el archivo a base de los "sub archivos" se vuelve imposible, en ocasiones no funcionan, en otras no envían y por ultimo se corrompen y no hay forma de solucionarlos.

Conocen o saben de alguna forma de completar esto?

Algunos enlaces para entender un poco mas sobre .ibd

1. [¿Que son?](https://filext.com/file-extension/IBD)
2. [Como usarlos](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-enterprise-backup-3.8-en/partial.restoring.single.html)
3. [Como se restauran](https://scriptinside.blogspot.com/2016/04/restaurando-archivos-ibd-en-tablas.html)

Gracias de antemano!